# Perfect Power detection in linear time

Tags: c, performance, algebra, computation

I'm trying to write a C program which, given a positive integer n (> 1) detect whether exists numbers x and r so that n = x^r

This is what I did so far:

```
while (c>=d) {
    double y = pow(sum, 1.0/d);
    if (floor(y) == y) {
        out = y;
        break;
    }

    d++;
}
```

In the program above, "c" is the maxium value for the exponent (r) and "d" will start by being equal to 2. Y is the value to be checked and the variable "out" is set to output that value later on. Basically, what the script does, is to check if the square roots of y exists: if not, he tries with the square cube and so on... When he finds it, he store the value of y in "out" so that: y = out^d

My question is, is there any more efficient way to find these values? I found some documentation online, but that's far more complicated than my high-school algebra. How can I implement this in a more efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant n = x^r, right?

Comment: Using floating point is a bad idea for finding anything perfect...

Comment: I'd worry about getting a "small" `y`: `floor(16.9999999999999999987643254532423) != 17`

Comment: In particular, using `floor` here is definitely wrong.

Comment: interesting! Thanks! But how can I fix it, then? I used it cause that was the only solution I've come up with...

Comment: May we assume `r` is going to be a positive integer?

Comment: Sure! No negative int on here at all...

Comment: The right question is, then, how can I check is a n-root of a certain number exists without using "floor"?

Comment: A solution that works for every `n` is `x = n`, `r = 1`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of your comments, you state you want this to be compatible with gigantic numbers. In that case, you may want to bring in the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/), which supports operations on arbitrarily large numbers, one of those operations being [checking if it is a perfect power](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Roots.html#Integer-Roots).

It is open source, so you can check out the source code and see how they do it, if you don't want to bring in the whole library.

Comment: Well, I've followed your suggestion and they do it through a gigantic complicated code in which I'll dive in right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `n` fits in a fixed-size (e.g. 32-bit) integer variable, the optimal solution is probably just hard-coding the list of such numbers and binary-searching it. Keep in mind, in `int` range, there are roughly

- `sqrt(INT_MAX)` perfect squares
- `cbrt(INT_MAX)` perfect cubes
- etc.

In 32 bits, that's roughly 65536 + 2048 + 256 + 128 + 64 + ... < 70000.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using unsigned long long int. I want the program to be compatible with gigantic numbers also...

Comment: In that case you'd need a several-gigabyte table.. :-) So other solutions might be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You need the r-base [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm), use an identity to calculate it using the [natural log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base)

So:

```
log_r(x) = log(x)/log(r)
```

So you need to calculate:

```
x = log(n)/log(r)
```

(In my neck of the wood, this *is* highschool math. Which immediately explains my having to look up whether I remembered that identity correctly :))

Comment: I didn't any logarithm :( How can I use this?

Comment: eg. [`double log(double x) -- Compute log(x).`](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/log.htm) in [math.h](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/math.h.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

After you are calculating y in

```
double y = pow(sum, 1.0/d);
```

you can get the nearest int to it and you can use your own power function to check for the
equality condition with sum.

```
int x = (int)(y+0.5);
int a = your_power_func(x,d);
if (a == sum)
     break;
```

I guess this way you can confirm whether a number is integer power of some other number or not.